# Vagrant error message missing line numbers on Windows

Tags: windows-7, vagrant

I have an error in my Vagrantfile somewhere:

```
C:\Users\myuser\repos\centos-ansible-box>vagrant up
Installing plugins: vagrant-proxyconf
There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded
and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by
a syntax error.

Path: C:/Users/myuser/repos/centos-ansible-box/Vagrantfile
Line number: /Users/myuser/repos/centos-ansible-box/Vagrantfile
Message: TypeError: no implicit conversion from nil to integer
```

What's wrong with my line number? It's really hard to try to guess what's wrong without that.

I'd guess this doesn't happen to all the users since I could not find a bug report, and I didn't find anyone else complaining, so I'm puzzled.

Example Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

foo
```

And output:

```
C:\Users\myuser\repos\test>vagrant up
There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded
and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by
a syntax error.

Path: C:/Users/myuser/repos/test/Vagrantfile
Line number: /Users/myuser/repos/test/Vagrantfile
Message: NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object
```

Using Vagrant version 1.7.4.

---

Edit: on Mac OS X using the same version, 1.7.4, the error message is as it should be:

```
$ vagrant up
There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded
and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by
a syntax error.

Path: /Users/myuser/repos/vagrant-test/Vagrantfile
Line number: 4
Message: NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object
```

So it seems to be Windows-only issue.

---

Edit2: I've now opened a [bug report](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6445) about it, since I can't figure out any other explanation.

Comment: please copy your Vagrantfile

Comment: @FrédéricHenri it's not related to my vagrantfile. This happens with any vagrant file that I have that has any kind of error.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri added an example file now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [confirmed as a bug and fixed in the trunk](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6445).